# How many times submit button would get clicked with impicit wait of 30 seconds

Tags: selenium

I'm having a situation and don't have the answer , I have  a login page where i am trying to click on Submit button but somehow when it clicks on submit button it doesnt navigate to homepage.

So my question is considering i have a implicit wait of 30 seconds how many times it would click the submit button?Will it keep on clicking until 30 sec and then throw an exception ?

Comment: How many times does your code tell it to click? It's hard to say with no code shown.

Comment: it would be like this that impicit wait set=30 sec and then submit.click(). So only one time click operation is performed. So what if click doesnt work first time , then will it try to keep clicking for 30 sec as per implicit wait defined?

Comment: It will only click once... but only after the element to be clicked is present. The implicit wait just retries locating the element until either it's found or it times out.

Answer (score 1):

The Implicit Wait would not click the element multiple times - in other words, it is not applied to the actions, it works for the "find" functionality only:

> An implicit wait is to tell WebDriver to poll the DOM for a certain amount of time when trying to find an element or elements if they are not immediately available.

What you are probably looking for is the [Explicit Wait](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits) - for instance, *waiting for a button to become clickable*. Example in Python:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
button = wait.until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "myDynamicElement"))
)
button.click()
```

Answer (score 1):

The implicit wait functionality is different from what you are expecting. It only checks for the element at regular intervals of time, this is called polling. If the element is found on the first time itself, then it will stop polling automatically. This means that it checks for the element until it is found with a time span of what you have given, in this case it is 30 second, through polling.

If you want to hit the element multiple times you can use an explicit wait like fluent wait.

If you want to wait for navigating to home page after clicking on submit, then use web driver wait, and your code will run smoothly.

```
      WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(big,120);
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("your xpath here"));
```